# Subconsulta con NOT IN en SQL usando BIGQUERY

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-bigquery

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta (que posee una subconsulta), la cual no me arroja ningún valor cuando la utilizo con NOT IN, pero cuando quito el NOT, sí me trae valores.
Lo primero que se me ocurrió fue que no me trae ningún valor, porque efectivamente no hay un valor que cumpla con las condiciones, pero eso no es así, ya que hay valores que cumplen con las condiciones.

El objetivo del query es el siguiente:
Quiero obtener los Install_Id que realizaron el evento 'game_started', pero sin haber realizado el evento 'onboarding_start'

```
WITH onb_start AS (
                    SELECT DISTINCT install_id
                    FROM data.fact_events
                    WHERE event_name = 'onboarding_start'),
     all_events AS (
                    SELECT t2.install_id,t2.event_name
                    FROM data.fact_events t2 
                    INNER JOIN onb_start ON t2.install_id = onb_start.install_id)


SELECT 
FROM all_events
WHERE all_events.install_id NOT IN(SELECT install_id 
                                   FROM data.fact_events 
                                   WHERE event_name ='game_started')
```

Comment: Hola! El código va como texto, al igual que los errores. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Pon tu codigo como texto

Comment: Listo! Ya lo corregí como texto.

Comment: Si pusieras un ejemplo con datos reales seria mas facil entenderte, pon tambien la estructura de tus tablas, necesitamos todos los detalles posibles y con la mayor claridad para poderte ayudar

Comment: Intercambia `onboarding_start` con `game_started`. Así como lo tienes estás buscando los que hicieron el onboarding sin haber hecho game_started